# how to strart a backend java project using spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, backend, implementation

I am starting a spring boot java project. I know I should not to code in the main method and the     principal class.

Is this a bad way?:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class CesckproApplication implements CommandLineRunner{

    @Autowired
    private ProcesoPrincipal pp;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {            
        SpringApplication.run(CanalCorSdqsApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {       
        pp.consulta();      
        // mycode here....  
    }
}
```

There is an other way to execute the code in other classes without touch the main class? i saw some like:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class CanalCorSdqsApplication{

    @Autowired
    private ProcesoPrincipal pp;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {            
        SpringApplication.run(CanalCorSdqsApplication.class, args);       
    }
}
```

And:

```
@Component
public class ProcesoPrincipal  implements CommandLineRunner {


    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {       
         consulta();        
     }

    public void consulta(){
        // my code here
    }   

}
```

There is an other way to do it? and what your expertice say about? (some time many of docs and tutrorial use to code in for example MAIN method cus it is just playful not a real aplication when you dont use the main to code all).

Comment: `what the documentation say about?` reading documentation yourself is actually easier then asking someone else to do it for you ...

Comment: @rkosegi it´s more like. what a person with big experience think is a good practice. cus I had read some docs ans do some tutorial but its normal that in this both use to do minimal example a simple example but in real context you can not code all in the main like some of tutorial do.  maybe that questinon was incorrect but I mean docs some time dont tell you how to do some in a big projects.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to understand **Spring-boot**, well you are lucky. There are brilliant sources of information with plenty of examples to go over in https://spring.io/guides and https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot

Don't take shortcuts to learning; Fail, build, learn and repeat.

These questions you ask:

- How to start a backend project?
- Is this a bad way?
- Is there any other way to execute code, if not in Main?

All of the will have an answer within a couple of tutorials, but if you still do not know which one to pick, go with this one: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-start